# Getting NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot create an NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a nil model'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

This code was working fine on xCode 6 beta 4 and after beta 5 I am getting this issue.

I get `ManagedObjectContext` as nil when i try to create an instance of `AppDelegate`.
Check the screenshot below.
[image]

I get exception on line 21 and if you see the `NSManagedObjectContext` is `nil`. So how should i create an instance of `AppDelegate` then in Swift.
Also I noticed that in Delegate method ManagedObject is now a Lazy Var rather then only var. 
As per the Swift document it says it will only be computed until its used for once. So wondering if i need to declare something for this?

Code for reference:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    var appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
    var currentrequest  =   NSFetchRequest(entityName: "SomeEntity")
    currentrequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    results = context.executeFetchRequest(currentrequest, error: nil    )
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code were you initialize your managed object context?

Comment: Ya sure. Added in main post.

Comment: Oh, I was not precise in question, sorry :) Can you please share the code from `AppDelegate` where you initialize MOC?

Comment: Its the default delegate which generates when you create a project using core data. Let me upload that to my dropbox. Here is the link to access. https://www.dropbox.com/s/ef8g8g05ipvklmt/AppDelegate.swift

Comment: managedObjectModel return `nil` when gets invoked from `persistentStoreCoordinator`. Check if you have `Places.xcdatamodeld` ('d' at the end) file in you project? And check if it is added to the target?

Comment: Hey Keenle. Thanks. Looks like i did a mistake with the spelling in the URL resource. This problem is solved. Thanks a lot for helping and pointing me out with possible place to see.

Comment: Hi Keenle, would you mind putting your reply as an answer and i can make this as solved then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58775/discussion-between-kd-and-keenle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code of AppDelegate.swift that you've posted, I can assume that either model name spelled incorrectly in `managedObjectModel` function or xcdatamodeld file has not been added to the target.

And as you confirmed in comments to the question, there was a problem in the spelling of URL resource to get model from the bundle.